# Javascript not running until refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, trello

My code just grabs trello board name, put it into curly brackets, and insert it into text area when clicking "add a card". However, it doesn't insert the board name into text area unless I refresh the page.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.js-open-card-composer').click(function() {
        setTimeout(addTitle, 100);
    });


});


function addTitle() {
        var boardName;
        boardName = document.title.replace(' | Trello', '');
        $('.list-card-composer-textarea').each(function() {
            $(this).val('{' + boardName + '}');
        });
}
```

I've already tried $(window).load.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you give a minimal example of the problem in the form of a snippet or fiddle?

Comment: can you console.log `$('.js-open-card-composer')` in the ready function and console.log `$('.list-card-composer-textarea')` in the addTitle function and make sure they both find something.

Comment: Until I refresh the page, `$('.js-open-card-composer')`'s length is 0 and `$('.list-card-composer-textarea')` doesn't show up. After refreshing, js-open-card-composer's length becomes greater than 0 and .list-card-composer-textarea shows up then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind to the body not to the element incase it doesnt exist

```
$('body').on('click', '.js-open-card-composer',function() {
   //probably don't need the timeout anymore 
   setTimeout(addTitle, 100);
});
```

Comment: I tried it with timeout and without timeout, they both don't even show board name this time.

Comment: do you have a body tag in your html?